# Find a vector components value in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, equations

I have thw following problem

Considering the matrix

```
M = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 10]
```

And the vector

```
E = [Ex; Ey; Ez]
```

And

```
B = [1; 4; 10]
```

Does anyone knows how to find the values of E components in matlab, considering

```
M*E=B?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following command, using [mldivide](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html?refresh=true) or the equivalent operator `\`:

```
E = M\B
```

This results in:

```
E =

    4.0000
   -6.0000
    3.0000
```

Verification:

```
M*E
```

ans =

```
 1.0000
 4.0000
10.0000
```

Comment: I understood your thoughts but shouldn't it be: E = B\M?

Comment: Nope, please check the description and syntax of `mldivide` provided by the mathworks. It solves the equation `Ax = B` for x, using `x = A\B`

Comment: Furthermore, it doesn't hurt to accept a correct answer... :)

Comment: Ops. Sorry about that! Accepted now! =D

Comment: DO you know how can I do the same thing in Python?

Comment: Sorry @Mac, I don't know anything about Python... Well I know that it's a snake :)